# Scraping from a website using puppeteer and cheerio returns an empty string

Tags: javascript, puppeteer, cheerio

I have been working on a node.js scraper using puppeteer and cheerio, and I'm not sure where my code is going wrong. I need to pull the information where it says

> Rated: Good

from [this page](https://directory.goodonyou.eco/brand/adidas). Below is my script, what is happening is that `this.rating` is just an empty string, when it should be "Rated: Good"

```js
constructor(browser, page) {
        this.browser = browser;
        this.page = page;

        //this.rating = "";
        this.url = "https://directory.goodonyou.eco/brand/adidas";
    }

    /**
     * @method main
     */
    async main(){
        await this.page.goto(this.url, {waitUntil: "domcontentloaded"});
        this.content = await this.page.content();
        
        const $ = cheerio.load(this.content);
        this.rating = $('#root > div > div.sc-hEsumM.EKgJr > div.sc-ktHwxA.cTYmXB > div:nth-child(1) > div.StyledBox-sc-13pk1d4-0.jtgCKU > div.StyledBox-sc-13pk1d4-0.ezgJqo > div > div.StyledBox-sc-13pk1d4-0.IRSNj > span:nth-child(1)').text();
        
        console.log(this.rating);
        this.writeToJson();
    }
```

This is my first time writing in JS so please be nice!

Comment: I didn't use puppeteer, so I can't make sure to answer your question correctly. But what I can confirm is the website you're scraping, generate the HTML nodes with a randomly class name. So you can't just copy the CSS selector from Chrome since the `div`'s class name changes per session.

Comment: So open your Chrome, fire up the console, and try to select that node with `document.querySelector` but not with the class names. After you have done, try new selector with puppeteer again.

Comment: @CasimirCrystal how would I do that? I thought that document.querySelector took the path as the parameter, and I'm not sure how else I could access the the div with that.

Answer (score 0):

It's the svg with opacity: 1 that you want. To get it's position:

```
let rating = await page.evaluate(() => 5 - [...document.querySelectorAll('svg[style*="opacity: 1"] ~ svg')].length)
```

(for this one it gives 4)